# How to fetch information in XML format from Nutch spidered webpages database

Tags: xml, nutch, aggregation, text-mining

I'm trying to build books aggregation portal. Nutch provides me excellent web crawler, but I want very specific information like, book title, book price, ISBN, author etc. How to extract that information from the crawled pages? I would like to fetch this information in XML format if possible.

In addition to the above, I would like to ask if this is the right approach! Can it be done in better way with other open source software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how structured the data is.

I assume you are crawling mostly HTML pages.

Oftentimes you can use [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XPath) to grab portions of the page, such as "//div[@class='books']/a/text()"

If much of the text is unstructured (no structured HTML patterns to grab), then you are going to have to use regular expressions or information extraction.

If you're lucky, you can do some/most of it using regular expressions.

For some more complicated structures, you'd need to use information extraction / named entity recognition.

You would have to train an IE tool, such as [Stanford's CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) to recognize, say, book titles and annotate them in your documents. Also check out [BRAT Rapid Annotation Tool](http://brat.nlplab.org/index.html).

Services like Mozenda can do the crawling and X-Path work for you, but I haven't seen a company that provides IE services.